# Vertx : insert array of objects into my database without without for loop

Tags: vert.x

I have an array of json object which i want to insert into my database, and instead of using a loop 'for' I'd like to use stored procedure, my question is how to do it without using the add method of jsonArray because as i see it takes one by one my records.

For example I have an array like this : [{'website': 'stackoverflow', 'description': 'very useful'}, {'website' : 'google', 'description' : 'huge informations'}] and I don't want to use it like this :

```
for(i=0;i<ja.size();i++){
   JsonArray params = new JsonArray();
   params.add('website',ja.getJsonObject(i).getValue("website")).add('website',ja.getJsonObject(i).getValue("description"));
}
```

Regards.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you want. Maybe you could provide an example output of what you want.

Comment: Hi will, I have to send array of json from view to database, my purpose is instead of using loop I want to send my array to Stored procedure which will handle dynamic insert in my database.

Comment: I think that, whenever you use a stored procedure or not, you need to call it in a way it can understand the input parameters...and usually, you need them all (as input), so you have to loop over them. I don't think you want (or can) handle a JSON input on the database itself. At least to me, looks like, in the way you are asking, you want to send the JSON payload to the database right away.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I want to avoid blocking methods that's why I would to do all the job in my SP, but it seems I have to use blocking handlers.

Comment: You can go non-blocking without using SP. Have a look, for instance, to the [mod-mysql-postgresql](https://github.com/vert-x/mod-mysql-postgresql).